# Counter Simulation - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, counter

I have a scenario where I need to do this:

TABLE: `UDA_VALUES`
It has three fields:

```
UDA_ID, UDA_VALUE_ID, UDA_VALUE_DESC
```

The Data for the table is like:

```
UDA_ID   UDA_VALUE_ID
  1          100
  1          243
  2          264
  3          564
  3          634
  3          774
```

I need to show the data like:

```
UDA_ID    COUNTER   UDA_VALUE_ID
  1          1            100
  1          2            243
  2          1            264
  3          1            564
  3          2            634
  3          3            774
```

How can I write the Counter?

Answer (score 5):

use window function `row_number()`

```
select UDA_ID,row_number() over(partition by UDA_ID order by UDA_VALUE_ID) counter, UDA_VALUE_ID
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT v.UDA_ID,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM UDA_VALUES AS _v
        WHERE _v.UDA_ID = v.UDA_ID) AS COUNTER,
       v.UDA_VALUE_ID
FROM UDA_VALUES AS v
```

for better performance you can use :

```
SELECT v.UDA_ID,
       counter.COUNTER,
       v.UDA_VALUE_ID 
FROM UDA_VALUES AS v
     INNER JOIN (SELECT _v.UDA_ID,
                        COUNT(*) AS COUNTER
                 FROM UDA_VALUES AS _v
                 GROUP BY _v.UDA_ID) AS counter ON counter.UDA_ID = v.UDA_ID
```